# Visual studio меняет кодировку у файлов при редактировании проекта

Tags: visual-studio, кодировка, reporting-services

Открываю решение в Visual studio, редактирую проект SQL Server Reporting Services. Сохраняю.
До редактирования файлы были в кодировке UTF-8, а после редактирования кодировка меняется на Windows-1251.

В файлах проекта содержатся символы кириллицы, и при повторном открытии Visual studio не может распознать символы и проект нельзя открыть.
Если вручную у файла поменять кодировку обратно на UTF-8, то все работает. Но файлов в проекте много и каждый раз менять кодировку не хотелось бы.

Попробовала в студии включить галочку "Сохранять документы в формате Юникод, если данные не возможно сохранить в выбранной кодировке"
Попробовала в винде включить флаг для не юникод приложений.
Не помогло.

Как сделать так, что бы Visual studio не меняла кодировку автоматически?
Может где-то внутри проекта Reporting Services можно принудительно указать кодировку?

Версия решения: VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.25420.1
Открываю решение в Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Версия 16.6.5
Другой человек открывает данный проект в 19 студии и редактирует его, у него проблема не повторяется.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41335199/13970074